# Kafka Streams shuts down on TopicAuthorizationException

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

We have an underlying issue in Kafka broker on IBM Cloud where our kafka consumers (both *Spring ListenerConsumer* & *KafkaStreams*) occasionally get the exception **org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TopicAuthorizationException** while running/polling

We overcame this issue in Kafka listeners by setting **AuthorizationExceptionRetryInterval** which means kafka will retry until exception is resolved. All good here

```
[ consumer-0-C-1] o.a.k.c.consumer.internals.Fetcher       : [Consumer clientId=consumerxxx_processing00b773de-064b-4c6f-8d0b-31a06de5ea93-14, 
groupId=xxx-00b773de-064b-4c6f-8d0b-31a06de5ea93] 
Not authorized to read from partition xxx_topic_name-2.

2021-11-02 01:15:10.086 ERROR [XXX] 1 --- [ consumer-0-C-1] essageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer : Authorization Exception, retrying in 30000 ms
```

However, we could not find something similar when it comes to kafka streams and hence our streams are being shutdown

```
2021-11-02 01:15:10.094 ERROR [xxx] 1 --- [-StreamThread-1] o.a.k.s.p.internals.StreamThread         : stream-thread [xxx-8c944f68-9bb5-488c-89c69271200e84c4-StreamThread-1] 
Encountered the following exception during processing and the thread is going to shut down:

org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TopicAuthorizationException: Not authorized to access topics: [xxx_topic_name]
```

Our apps can detect the stream has gone down so will start it again after some time. This does not seem to be ideal. Would have loved spring kafka handle it for us under the hood.

Can anyone think of a better workaround?

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with Spring; with Apache Kafka streams, it just assists in creating the streams in a Spring-friendly way; it has no involvement with the runtime characteristics of the streams themselves. It has much more control when using the consumer and producer APIs.

One thing you could try is to set the `StreamsBuilderFactoryBean` `autoStartup` property to `false` to prevent Spring from trying to start it during context initialization.

Assuming the exception is thrown during the `start()` method, you could programmatically start the bean in a loop (with a delay) until successful; you can use your own logic for that, or something like a `RetryTemplate` from spring-retry.

If the authorization exceptions happen at runtime (after the stream has been running for a while), I have no suggestions for that (other than what you are currently doing).

Comment: Thanks Gary, quite possible that issue can occur on start up in which case what you suggested sounds right. However in our case (at least mostly) it happens when streams are already running. Apache Kafka streams shuts the stream down on first occurrence of this exception.

This is the place where we see an exception and hence shutdown of the stream 
**org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run()**

Comment: One thing you could try is to add an `UncaughtExceptioHandler` (replaced by the `StreamsUncaughtExceptionHandler` in spring-kafka 2.8 to be released soon) to the `StreamsBuilderFactoryBean` and use that to schedule restarting.

Comment: Thanks a lot Gary. That works

Answer (score 0):

As Gary rightly suggested, we can sum the answer as below

**Problem occurred at Start up** - Set the `StreamsBuilderFactoryBean` `autoStartup` property to false to prevent Spring from trying to start it during context initialization. And programmatically start the bean in a loop (with a delay) until successful; you can use your own logic for that, or something like a `RetryTemplate` from spring-retry.

**Problem when Stream was already running** - add an `UncaughtExceptioHandler` (replaced by the `StreamsUncaughtExceptionHandler` in `spring-kafka 2.8` to be released soon) to the `StreamsBuilderFactoryBean` and use that to schedule restarting